# Assembly accessed via NuGet package doesn't include a class

Tags: xaml, uwp, nuget, nuget-package, uwp-xaml

A Universal Class Library (UWP) project that I created has two classes;

1.
    A `public BoolToVisibilityConverter` - an `IValueConverter` whose responsibility it is to convert a `bool` to a XAML `Visibility`, and vice-versa.

2.
    A `public CustomControl` templated control whose template (defined in `Themes\Generic.xaml` (project structure below)) uses the `BoolToVisibilityConverter` mentioned above.

Its template looks like this;

```
<Border ...>
    <Border.Resources>
        <local:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />
    </Border.Resources>
    <Grid ...>
        <Grid ...
            Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

`Value`, the property the `Visibility` is bound to, is a `bool`ean dependency property on the control, `local` being an alias to the namespace within which the `BoolToVisibilityConverter` resides (which is the same as that of the templated control).

## Project Structure

[image: Project structure]

## Build Configurations

The `Release` build configuration of the project has the "XML documentation file" and "Generate library layout" options enabled.

[image: Build configuration]

## Generating a NuGet package

The NuSpec for my project (located at `NuGet\RefClassLibrary.nuspec`) is;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
    <metadata>
        <id>RefClassLibrary</id>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <!-- various other metadata -->
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="..\bin\Release\**" target="lib\uap10.0"/>
    </files>
</package>
```

The file was generated using the `nuget.exe spec` command, with the NuGet CLI version 4.3.0.4406.

To generate the NuGet package, I first deleted the `bin` and `obj` folders, and built the project in the `Release (Any CPU)` configuration, which generated the following structure in the `bin` folder,

[image: Bin structure]

I then generated the NuGet package for the class library using the command `nuget.exe pack RefClassLibrary.nuspec` from within the `NuGet\` folder, which generated a `nupkg` file with the following structure,

[image: nupkg structure]

## Problem: Consuming the class library via the NuGet package

From within a new Universal Windows Application project I ran the `Install-Package` commmand with the absolute path to the `nupkg` as its argument, within the Package Manager Console within Visual Studio, which installed the generated package.

After building the project (without errors), I added the following XAML to a new Blank Page,

```
<Page ...
    xmlns:rcl="using:RefClassLibrary">
    <Grid ...>
        <rcl:CustomControl Width="200" Height="200" Value="True"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Which resulted in an error that reads,

```
XamlParseException: The text associated with this error code could not be found.

Cannot deserialize XBF metadata type list as 'BoolToVisibilityConverter' was not found in namespace 'RefClassLibrary'. [Line: 0 Position: 0]

StackTrace:
at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Control.ApplyTemplate()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.UwpDesigner.InstanceBuilders.WindowsUIXamlLocalInstanceManager.EnsureElementInDictionary(Object root, ViewNode knownAncestor)

InnerException: None
```

[image: error]

Upon viewing `RefClassLibrary` in the Object Browser, sure enough as the error suggests, the `BoolToVisibilityConverter` class wasn't there...

[image: object browser]

## Consuming the class library directly

I used the `Uninstall-Package RefClassLibrary` command to remove the package from the project.

I then unzipped the `nupkg` file using the command `7z x RefClassLibrary.1.0.0.nupkg -oOut`, which extracts it to a folder `Out`, and directly referenced the `dll` contained within the `Out\lib\uap10.0\` folder within the project by adding a Reference via Solution Explorer, **which made it work perfectly**. The `BoolToVisibilityConverter` did show up in the Object Browser.

## How should this issue be fixed?

The correct assembly gets included within the NuGet package, although some parts of it (?) don't get 'imported' into the project...

Comment: I tested your nuget package and cannot reproduce your issue. What's your vs version? I used visual studio 2017,15.3.5

Comment: Apologies for the delay in replying. @SunteenWu-MSFT I can't remember exactly what version of Visual Studio I was using, but I updated to 2017 Community `15.4.1` and the issue still persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a NuGet package is installed via the `Install-Package` Cmdlet, this is, *as I understand*, what NuGet does,

1. The identifier and version number of the package to be installed are retrieved. It does so via the specified arguments (in the case of a version number not being specified, it defaults to the latest 'stable' version), or by reading the contents of the package that it points to.
2. The `.nupkg` file and some other assets associated with the package are copied to and cached within the `%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages\{identifier}\{version}\` folder.
3. The package is then extracted and installed within the Visual Studio project that you are in.

When you install the same version of the same package again, NuGet uses the cached files located within the aforementioned folder, instead of re-downloading them.

---

**The problem described in the question originated as a result of me not incrementing the version number of the NuGet package.**

I developed the library project in two steps on my machine,

1. I intially created the library project with only the `CustomControl`, generated the library package, and installed it in an external app project.
2. It was afterwards that I added the `BoolToVisibilityConverter`, re-generated the library package, and re-installed it in the app project.

The version number of the package (`1.0.0`) specified in the `.nuspec` file was not incremented between the first and second steps, and therefore the new package generated in step 2 was not used by NuGet because a package with the same identifier and version number was already cached at `%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages\`.

This would explain why it worked (refer to the comments on the question) for [Sunteen Wu - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5620055/sunteen-wu-msft) (thanks!).

**So, solution is to** either,

1. Increment the version number in the `.nuspec` file, or,
2. Delete the folder that corresponds to the package (or version thereof), located within the `%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages` folder,

...after which you would re-generate the library package with the same version number, and install it in the app project.